# Query based on 2 tables where duplicate id's amounts are calculated

Tags: mysql, database

I Have 2 tables, table **ONE** consist of an `category_id` where each has its own not unique `name` attribute and each `product_id` would be unique in this table with no duplicates.

Table **TWO** consist of unique `product_id` just like table **ONE** and `rank` based on the biggest `amount`.

Table : **ONE**

```
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+
  | brd_id | cat_id  | product_id |  name  |
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+
  |      1 |       1 | 333        |    w   |
  |      2 |       1 | 444        |    w   |
  |      3 |       1 | 555        |    w   |
  |      4 |       2 | 666        |    y   |
  |      5 |       2 | 777        |    y   |
  |      6 |       3 | 888        |    t   |
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Table: **TWO**

```
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+--------+
  | new_id |  type   | product_id |  rank  | amount |
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+--------+
  |      1 |    all  | 333        |    1   |    80  |
  |      2 |    all  | 444        |    2   |    70  |
  |      3 |    all  | 555        |    3   |    60  |
  |      4 |    all  | 666        |    4   |    50  |
  |      5 |    all  | 777        |    5   |    40  |
  |      6 |    all  | 888        |    6   |    30  |
  +--------+---------+------------+--------+--------+
```

What i want is to show `name` from table **ONE** only once based on the amount from table **TWO** WHERE in table **ONE** `product_id` has the same `cat_id`.

This i was able to achieve using this query basically straight from database so fields differ:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `cat`.`brand_name`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` 
ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%'
AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16
ORDER BY `cat_p`.`rank` ASC
```

**PROBLEM**

I get duplicate names, so i used `DISTINCT` which in the end ignores the duplicate values.

I want to calculate the `amount` where the `product_id` from table **ONE** is IN table **TWO** AND where they have the same category_id in table **ONE**.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
  +---------+--------+
  | cat_id  |  name  |   amount
  +---------+--------+
  |       1 |    w   |    210
  |       2 |    y   |     90
  |       3 |    t   |     30
  +--------+---------+
```

Hope it makes sense. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fiddle to work with, but I think this is right.

It MIGHT have typos.

The general idea is that we do the distinct FIRST nest it.  Then, once we get the distinct, then we get the SUM of the distinct elements from the secondary table.  The reason we do it this way is because otherwise the SUM (if done in the inside) would join multiple records and get an amount that is too high.

```
SELECT A.CAT_ID, A.BRAND_NAME,
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly P WHERE P.ID_PRODUCT=A.ID_PRODUCT) FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT  `cat`.`cat_id`, `cat`.`brand_name`, `cat_p`.`rank`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` 
ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%'
AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16
GROUP BY  `cat`.`cat_id`, `cat`.`brand_name`
) A
ORDER BY A.RANK
```

Comment: Nice man thanks for helping ill try and let you know, dont bother the typos i just want the solution idea behind my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT `cat`.`brand_name`, `cat_p`.`amount`, SUM(`cat_p`.`amount`) AS `sum_amount`
FROM `ps_product_brand` AS `cat`
INNER JOIN `ps_product_custom_statistics_weekly` AS `cat_p` ON `cat_p`.`id_product` = `cat`.`id_product`
WHERE `cat_p`.`type` LIKE '%all%' AND `cat_p`.`rank` <= 16
GROUP BY `cat`.`brand_name`
ORDER BY `sum_amount` DESC, `cat`.`brand_name`
```

Note the difference in numbers between amount and sum_amount where the duplicates are. You might have to increase the rank and possibly add LIMIT to the end.

Comment: Thanks , exactly what i was looking for!